# EF Core 2.x date subtraction/difference in Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, datediff, npgsql, ef-core-2.2

I am using Npgsql provider version 4.0.x and ef core 2.x. I have the following entities with navigation properties:

```
public class Entity : ...
{
   .....
   public ICollection<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
}

public class OtherEntity : ... 
{
   ...
   public int Order { get; set; }
   public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to perform the following query:

```
var query = provider.Query<Entity>()
     .Select(x => new 
     { 
         Difference = (x.OtherEntities.OrderBy(y => y.Order).FirstOrDefault().Date 
- x.OtherEntities.OrderByDescending(y => y.Order).FirstOrDefault().Date).TotalDays
     })
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

But it does not work :( No warnings or whatever, simply skips my `Select` query.
I found out that there are default DbFunctions hidden in EF.Functions.DateDiff* layer, but these are working only if using SQL Server provider. Is there any way to perform this in Npgsql? 
I tried to implement custom database user function named `DATE_PART` (which is a Postgres feature), but it calculates only days/hours/month, and I can't combine these. I need format of `TimeSpan.TotalDays` (the first part is a num of days and the fraction contains day hours).

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue... In a trivial test program, I'm seeing the following in my PostgreSQL logs: SELECT x."End" - x."Start" FROM "Blogs" AS x LIMIT 1

Comment: It's used as a subquery in sql function

Comment: Anyways, edited the code

Comment: That works well too, [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/roji/3d24e79b3662d70f67cc657e89918fe1). Please post a full code sample that reproduces your issue...

Comment: It looks like a weird bug. I am using it with postgis methods. When I try to call user-scalar function ST_LineInterpolatePoint and perform date calculations in the second parameter I get missing select and it does not work. but I don't think it's a postgis related problem. Because I can clearly see that ef core tries to perform select n+1 thing without any warning.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your issue - please post a simple, minimal code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll make a gist with this soon